# How fast can fully transaction Storm cluster process tuples?

Tags: bigdata, apache-storm

I understand that the bench mark for commodity hardware is around 10 nodes able to process 1 million tuples (each of size 10 MB?) per second. However, the term commodity hardware is vague and just to add a pinch of salt, is each node 8 core?

Also is this bench mark speed for a fully transactional base Storm cluster or a cluster that is configured for maximum efficiency?

Comment: it depends on hardware configuration, isn't it ?

Comment: yes, but i heard from a youtube video that mentioned that, thus i hope somebody who has experience can share the speed and hardware used.

Comment: Hi, I once did a simple spout-bolt benachmark (each parallelism of one) on two nodes (each nodes has two Xeon E5-2620 2GHz with 6 cores each; and both are connected via 1Gbit Ethernet; so the hardware was not utilized completely). I used tiny tuples of 4 bytes (ie, one integer value) and measssured the maximum data rate I could ship from spout to bolt. It was about 400,000 tuples per second. Fault-tolerance disabled.